# Custom-define contrast - mix between dummy and Helmert coding

Tags: r, regression, categorical-encoding, contrasts

I'm trying to use custom-defined contrasts. They are sort of a combination of traditional dummy coding and the last contrast produced by reversed Helmert coding.
In short, I want to compare each of the levels `A`, `B`, `C` with `Contr` (similar to dummy coding where `Contr` would be the reference category. Then I want a contrast comparing `(A+B+C)` to `Contr` (similar to reversed Helmert coding). I think I can define these by hand, but when trying to do it programatically in `R` I seem to produce something more similar to effects coding.

```r
set.seed(123)

custom_coding <- matrix(0, ncol=4, nrow=4)
colnames(custom_coding) <- c("A-Contr","B-Contr","C-Contr",
                             "All-Contr")
rownames(custom_coding) <- c("Contr","A","B","C")

> custom_coding
      A-Contr B-Contr C-Contr All-Contr
Contr       0       0       0         0
A           0       0       0         0
B           0       0       0         0
C           0       0       0         0

custom_coding["Contr",] <- -1

# A vs Cont
custom_coding["A", grep(x=colnames(custom_coding), pattern="A-Contr")] <- 1
# B vs Contr
custom_coding["B", grep(x=colnames(custom_coding), pattern="B-Contr")] <- 1
# C vs Contr
custom_coding["C", grep(x=colnames(custom_coding), pattern="C-Contr")] <- 1
# All vs Contr
custom_coding[c("A","B","C"), grep(x=colnames(custom_coding), pattern="All-Contr")] <- 1

> custom_coding
      A-Contr B-Contr C-Contr All-Contr
Contr      -1      -1      -1        -1
A           1       0       0         1
B           0       1       0         1
C           0       0       1         1
```

What I would like to achieve my goal, I think is this:

```
contrast_matrix <- 
matrix(rbind(c(-1,1,0,0),
          c(-1,0,1,0),
          c(-1,0,0,1),
          c(-3/3,1/3,1/3,1/3)),ncol=4,
          dimnames=list(c("A-Contr","B-Contr","C-Contr","All-Contr")))

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
A-Contr     -1 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
B-Contr     -1 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
C-Contr     -1 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
All-Contr   -1 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Is there a way `R` can produce this automatically?

What I'm doing below, seems to result in effects coding which is not what I want.

```r
dat <- bind_cols(data.frame(y=c(rnorm(n=10, mean=20, 3),
                                rnorm(n=10, mean=22, 3),
                                rnorm(n=10, mean=18, 3),
                                rnorm(n=10, mean=0, 5))),
      data.frame(type = c(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=10), 
      rep("Contr", 10)))) %>% 
      mutate(type=relevel(factor(type), ref="Contr"))

contrasts(dat$type) <- solve(t(custom_coding))

> dat$type
 [1] A     A     A     A     A     A     A     A     A     A     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     C     C     C     C     C     C     C     C     C     C    
[31] Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr
attr(,"contrasts")
      A-Contr B-Contr C-Contr
Contr    -0.5    -0.5    -0.5
A         0.5    -0.5    -0.5
B        -0.5     0.5    -0.5
C        -0.5    -0.5     0.5
Levels: Contr A B C
```

Even when using the previously defined `contrast_matrix` that I think is correct, the contrast for `All-Contr` drops, why?

##UPDATE
I clearly missed the k-1 constraint.

```
> contrasts(dat$type) <- t(contrast_matrix)
> dat$type
 [1] A     A     A     A     A     A     A     A     A     A     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     C     C     C     C     C     C     C     C     C     C    
[31] Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr Contr
attr(,"contrasts")
      A-Contr B-Contr C-Contr
Contr      -1      -1      -1
A           1       0       0
B           0       1       0
C           0       0       1
Levels: Contr A B C
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to define two contrasts with one matrix. To fit a model you have to choose one contrast, so that the model understands how to interpret the coefficients and estimate them.

Once you fit the model you can look at any number of comparisons between (functions of) the coefficients. For `lm`, `glm`, `gls` and `geepack::geese` linear models, you don't have to define the contrasts by hand; use the [contrast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/index.html) package instead.

```r
# Fit the model with the default treatment contrast. (Any contrast will do.)
fit <- lm(y ~ type, data = dat)

library("contrast")

# Example 1: Compare the control to each of the treatments.
print(
  contrast(
    fit,
    list(type = c("A", "B", "C")),
    list(type = "Contr")
  ),
  X = TRUE
)
#> lm model parameter contrast
#> 
#>  Contrast     S.E.    Lower    Upper     t df Pr(>|t|)
#>  18.61365 1.277391 16.02299 21.20432 14.57 36        0
#>  21.01564 1.277391 18.42497 23.60631 16.45 36        0
#>  15.11610 1.277391 12.52543 17.70677 11.83 36        0
#> 
#> Contrast coefficients:
#>  (Intercept) typeA typeB typeC
#>            0     1     0     0
#>            0     0     1     0
#>            0     0     0     1

# Example 2: Compare the control to the average of the treatments.
print(
  contrast(fit,
    list(type = c("A", "B", "C")),
    list(type = "Contr"),
    type = "average"
  ),
  X = TRUE
)
#> lm model parameter contrast
#> 
#>   Contrast     S.E.    Lower    Upper    t df Pr(>|t|)
#> 1 18.24847 1.042985 16.13319 20.36374 17.5 36        0
#> 
#> Contrast coefficients:
#>   (Intercept)     typeA     typeB     typeC
#> 1           0 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333

# Example 3: Compare the control to a weighted average of the treatments.
print(
  contrast(fit,
    list(type = c("A", "B", "C")),
    list(type = "Contr"),
    weights = c(1 / 2, 1 / 4, 1 / 4),
    type = "average"
  ),
  X = TRUE
)
#> lm model parameter contrast
#> 
#>   Contrast     S.E.    Lower    Upper     t df Pr(>|t|)
#> 1 18.33976 1.059157 16.19169 20.48783 17.32 36        0
#> 
#> Contrast coefficients:
#>   (Intercept) typeA typeB typeC
#> 1           0   0.5  0.25  0.25
```

As the examples show, a contrast is a linear combination of the factor levels; it can be represented as a row vector. If you can extract the coefficients and their covariance matrix from the fitted model, you can find the contrast and its standard error by hand.

```r
# Compute by hand the contrast that compares the control 
# to the average of the treatments.
X <- matrix(c(0, 1 / 3, 1 / 3, 1 / 3), nrow = 1)

# Find the value of the contrast
X %*% fit$coefficients
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 18.24847
# ... and its standard error.
sqrt(X %*% vcov(fit) %*% t(X))
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 1.042985
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Would you know how to manually do the same contrast from a fitted model?

Comment: By "do a contrast", do you mean to define it (ie. come up with the design matrix which corresponds to the comparison)? Or to compute it (ie. multiply the design matrix by the matrix of estimated coefficients)? I would avoid computing contrasts by hand as it's easy to get the linear algebra wrong. Look at the documentation for `?rms::contrast` and at the [`contrast`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/index.html) package. One or the other of these resources probably gets you what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was possible to define any comparison in the design matrix which would be carried through to the model matrix and to the model fit. Not only something you do once you have fitted the model post-hoc. In my case, I work on posterior distributions from a non-standard r format so I need to solve it manually. I’ll read up on the contrast package!

Comment: A contrast is a linear combination of the factor levels. And yes, you can choose any contrast to define the model matrix and fit the model. But you are interested in two different contrasts. Why fit the model twice to make these two comparisons? Instead fit the model once and then look at any number of comparisons.

Comment: You probably also want the standard error of the contrast, which might not be trivial with a non-standard model. It might be best to ask another question with more details about your model.